# Arduino interrupts

Tags: arduino, delay, esp32

I am working on a smart greenhouse project using an ESP32 as a microcontroller.

Data comes from a DHT22 temperature and humidity sensor and a soil moisture sensor. Those two tend to use `delay()` functions to read, because they need some time to warm up.

Example:

```
    void loop() {
  // Wait a few seconds between measurements.
  delay(2000);

  // Reading temperature or humidity takes about 250 milliseconds!
  // Sensor readings may also be up to 2 seconds 'old' (its a very slow sensor)
  float h = dht.readHumidity();
  // Read temperature as Celsius (the default)
  float t = dht.readTemperature();
  // Read temperature as Fahrenheit (isFahrenheit = true)
  float f = dht.readTemperature(true);
}
```

I am planning on posting this data on a web interface, which would have manual controls available too.
Since I am using delays, if I press the button on the website, first the delay executes, then the button press, so it's not instant. What could I do to fix that?

Comment: Just display a message that says "Warming up..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `delay()`. I'm not clear on exactly what you're trying to do here or how you're trying to handle the button, but in general you're better off doing something like this:

```
#define SENSOR_UPDATE_WARMUP 2000
#define SENSOR_UPDATE_INTERVAL 1000

void loop() {
  static unsigned long next_sensor_update = SENSOR_UPDATE_WARMUP;

  if(millis() > next_sensor_update) {
    // Reading temperature or humidity takes about 250 milliseconds!
    // Sensor readings may also be up to 2 seconds 'old' (its a very slow sensor)
    float h = dht.readHumidity();
    // Read temperature as Celsius (the default)
    float t = dht.readTemperature();
    // Read temperature as Fahrenheit (isFahrenheit = true)
    float f = dht.readTemperature(true);

    next_sensor_update = millis() + SENSOR_UPDATE_INTERVAL;
    }
}
```

This allows you to other processing in `loop()` while still having the warmup time and only updating the sensor readings periodically (adjust `SENSOR_UPDATE_INTERVAL` to the number of milliseconds between updates).

If you need to have other delays for other devices just repeat the pattern of having a static variable that tracks the timing for those devices.

Even simpler, you could just put the two second delay at the end of `setup()` rather than inside `loop()`, but I suspect you're not going to want to update the sensor values constantly, so you'll want to structure your program similarly to the code above.